# 2010s TV series about a cult of immortals

Tags: story-identification, tv

American (or Canadian) TV series. It wasn't on long and I only caught a couple of episodes.

If memory serves, the main character was an alcoholic writer who lives the Pacific Northwest. One day his wife leaves him without explanation. When he finally tracks her down she acts like a stranger with a completely different personality. She actually *is* a stranger, because she is a member of an ancient cult that has mastered immortality.

An immortal has to live a couple of decades of their new life before the cult triggers them (with some kind of physical object) and they remember their past lives.

The MC investigates this cult and they come to see him as a threat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the main character is a former cop (not sure about a writer), there's a good chance this is *Intruders* (2007).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intruders_(TV_series)):

> Jack Whelan is a former Los Angeles Police Department (LAPD) detective who is asked to investigate strange occurrences related to a string of attempted suicides. Despite his efforts, he is stumped. **He concentrates his search on a secret society, *Qui Reverti* (Latin for 'who return'), whose members chase immortality** by seeking refuge in the bodies of others after their own deaths. Agents of the society, called "Shepherds", **find the hosts of the returning souls and show them "triggers"––items important to the returning *Qui Reverti* members in their past lives––that "awaken" the returning soul.** Once awakened, the intruding soul engages in a battle of wills with the host's soul, with the losing soul sent to the afterlife. In Whelan's case, **this process destroys his marriage when his wife's body is taken by an intruder.**

---

Found with the Google query `scifi tv show cult immortals wife past lives site:en.wikipedia.org`.

Comment: John Simm seems to be attracted to projects that involve someone suddenly "waking up" in a different body.  [(1),](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_on_Mars_(British_TV_series)) [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_(Doctor_Who)#Professor_Yana_and_Harold_Saxon)

Comment: Thank you, Jenayah.